# Increase product price font size only on WooCommerce single product pages

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a coding to show only the lowest price for variable product which works perfectly fine (see below)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'move_variations_single_price', 1 );
function move_variations_single_price(){
    global $product, $post;

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        // removing the variations price for variable products
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

        // Change location and inserting back the variations price
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_variation_single_price', 10 );
    }
}

function replace_variation_single_price(){
    global $product;

    // Main Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
    $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    // Sale Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
    sort( $prices );
    $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    if ( $price !== $saleprice && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del> <ins>' . $price . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</ins>';
    }

    ?>
    <style>
        div.woocommerce-variation-price,
        div.woocommerce-variation-availability,
        div.hidden-variable-price {
            height: 0px !important;
            overflow:hidden;
            position:relative;
            line-height: 0px !important;
            font-size: 0% !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('select').blur( function(){
            if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ){
                if($('p.availability'))
                    $('p.availability').remove();
                $('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()).append('<p class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</p>');
                console.log($('input.variation_id').val());
            } else {
                $('p.price').html($('div.hidden-variable-price').html());
                if($('p.availability'))
                    $('p.availability').remove();
                console.log('NULL');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

    echo '<p class="price">'.$price.'</p>
    <div class="hidden-variable-price" >'.$price.'</div>';
}
```

Then, I used the following code to try increasing the font size for the pricing which works as well:

```css
span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

But it also affects all other pages such as the checkout page.

Is there a way to isolate this code just to effect the larger font size in the product summary area?

Comment: Please send your site url then i will provide css for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add below code in your child CSS file.

```
.single-product span.amount {

    font-size: 1.5em;

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This is no longer affecting the other pages but I forgot to mention one thing.  I show the shopping cart total dollar value at the header.  This code would still increase the font size of the shopping cart value at the header.  Would appreciate your further advice.  Thanks!